# how to get odoo binary field download link in website

Tags: odoo, odoo-website

I'm trying to get the download and filename of a file from the website.

model

```
class Files(models.Model):
    _name = 'website_downloads.files'
    name = fields.Char()
    file = fields.Binary('File')
```

controler

```
class website_downloads(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/downloads/', auth='public', website=True)
    def index(self, **kw):
        files = http.request.env['website_downloads.files']
        return http.request.render('website_downloads.index', {
            'files': files.search([]),
        })
```

template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="index" name="Website Downloads Index">
            <t t-call="website.layout">
                <div id="wrap" style="margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px">
                    <div class="container text-center">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <t t-foreach="files" t-as="f">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><t t-esc="f.name"/></td>
                                    **<td>Download</td>**
                                </tr>
                            </t>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

How can I get the download link, and when saving the file in the db save de original filename

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Odoo comes with a built-in `/web/binary/saveas` controller, that can be used for exactly this purpose:

```
<t t-foreach="files" t-as="f">
    <tr>
        <td><t t-esc="f.name"/></td>
        <td><a t-attf-href="/web/binary/saveas?model=website_downloads.files&amp;field=file&amp;filename_field=name&amp;id={{ f.id }}">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
</t>
```

The controller takes four arguments:

- `model` - the name of the model with the `Binary` field
- `field` - the name of the `Binary` field
- `id` - id of the record containing particular file.
- `filename_field` - name of a `Char` field containing file's name (optional).

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know how to name the model as the original filename?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: On the model form, when the user select the file, the file is store in the database as binary string but the filename is lost, is there a way to restore that filename?

Comment: You need a separate `Char` field for holding the filename information. This field name should be the value of the `filename_field` parameter for the `/web/binary/saveas` url. The `Binary` field in your view takes a `filename` parameter which should be set to the same `Char` field name (for example `<field name="file" filename="filename"/>`). This will automatically set the filename as the field's value. If this explanation is not enough it would be helpful if you ask a separate question, as this is a separate issue.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer Hi Good Day!, can you help me with this I've create a download link but an Error had occured while trying to download my file "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this document." tried to sudo it but it is no use

Comment: @BlackandWhite the object obviously needs to be publicly accessible. Check both your access rules and record rules.